# ldap authentication issue with the right credentials

Tags: authentication, search, ldap

I am connecting to my ldap account "myApp" and trying to authenticate "usernumber".

My connection string for logging in to the ldap account is :

```
security.ldap.cert.userDn=uid=myApp,ou=Org Unit,ou=application,dc=XXX,dc=com
security.ldap.cert.password=mypassword
```

My search filter for the user number is:

```
<property name="searchFilter" value="usernumber={0}" />
<property name="searchBasePattern" value="ou=User,o=network" />
```

I am obtaining :

```
Your login attempt was unsuccessful. Please try again.
Cause: Bad credentials
```

I tried different usernumber's and its corresponding passwords. Even created a new usernumber to make sure it is actually there in the ldap server. But still showing the same error. Could there be any other reasons for this?
Will there be different privileges for different ldap accounts??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question you provide 2 separate things:

1. Your DN and Password.
2. Some parameters for search.

In order to search in the LDAP, you need to "connect" (aka "bind") to it - this is where #1 is used. The error message could be related to this step so double check your DN and the corresponding password.

To verify user's password, you need to know user DN. Therefore it is often necessary to connect to the LDAP with technical/application credentials you have in #1, then search for the user using #2 and finally when you've got the user's DN, you perform a check by "connecting" with the found DN and user's password.

Comment: My "connect" (aka "bind") is working fine. I checked it by giving wrong values for it. And I am obtaining Ldap error. But my issue is specific to user dn,I guess. My users are under node "usernumber" and I double checked if they are actually there .My framework is checking the user dn and password for me and bringing me the message bad credentials.

Comment: Does DN of a user look like this: "usernumber=xxx,ou=User,o=network"? Note that you should use a complete user DN and it might be that it does not necessarily have "usernumber=xxx" in it but e.g. "uid=yyy,ou=User,o=network".

Comment: I have connected to my ldap and now i have to check whether that usernumber is there or not. Each user trying to login should be checked if it is there or not. The user DN is "usernumber=xxx,ou=User,o=network". But it just that i have to validate all the users trying to login. So I am giving "searchBasePattern" value="ou=User,o=network" and "searchFilter" value="usernumber={0}". I believe this is the correct way to do it.